# How to make sqlite3 module not converting column data to integer type

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to read data from a sqlite3 database using python3 and it looks as it tries to be smart and convert columns looking like a integer to integer type. I don't want that (if I got it right sqlite3 stores data as text no matter what anyway).

I've created the database as:

```
sqlite> create table t (id integer primary key, foo text, bar datetime);
sqlite> insert into t values (NULL, 1, 2);
sqlite> insert into t values (NULL, 1, 'fubar');
sqlite> select * from t;
1|1|2
2|1|fubar
```

and tried to read it using:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM t")

for l in cur:
    print(t)

db.close()
```

And getting output like:

```
(1, '1', 2)
(2, '1', 'fubar')
```

but I expected/wanted something like

```
('1', '1', '2')
('2', '1', 'fubar')
```

(definitely for the last column)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for l in cur:
    print((str(x) for x in t))
```

Comment: Yes, but then `None` will become `"None"` - so I can't distinguish between `NULL` cells from cells containing the text `"None"` - this is however what I do for now and hope I will not encounter `NULL` cells.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite stores values in whatever [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) the column has.

If you do not want to have numbers, don't use `datetime` but `text`.